# R: remove same entry from all nested lists

Tags: r, nested-lists

Given a nested list like this:

```
list_original <- list(list1 = list(foo = 1, bar = 2), list2 = list(foo = 1, bar = 2))
```

How can I remove the same names entry from all of the nested lists. For example, removing the `foo` entry from all nested lists in `list_original`, to give this result:

```
list_final <- list(list1 = list(bar = 2), list2 = list(bar = 2))
```

In reality I need to remove the entry from over 100000 nested lists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lapply` to set `foo` in each list to `NULL`:

**Code:**

```
list_original <- list(list1 = list(foo = 1, bar = 2), list2 = list(foo = 1, bar = 2))
list_final <- lapply(list_original, function(x) {
  x[["foo"]] <- NULL
  x
})
list_final
```

**Output:**

```
$list1
$list1$bar
[1] 2


$list2
$list2$bar
[1] 2
```